# Flurry Android events not logging through NDK but logging through java

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, flurry

I am trying to integrate flurry into a NativeActivity (no-java based code) Android application, and am not having any success. I have set up a sister Java-based flurry test activity that works well, but the native calls seem to be the ones not getting through

In the manifest file, I have the permissions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

```java
package com.myTest.flurry;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;

public class FlurryActivity extends Activity {

    //code has correct api key here
    private static final String appKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flurry);
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, appKey);
        FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
        FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
        FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
        FlurryAgent.logEvent("Starting up!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
    }
}
```

Which simply enough makes the events show up on the flurry website. However, when calling the same functions through my native code, the events do not show up

```cpp
#include "flurry.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/native_activity.h>
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>
#include "log.h"

JNIEnv *GetEnv(JavaVM *jvm);
void DetachEnv(JavaVM *jvm);

Flurry::Flurry()
    : state_(0) {
}

jclass Flurry::GetFlurryAgentClass(JNIEnv *env) {
  // Extract the FlurryAgent class
  jobject nativeActivity = state_->activity->clazz;
  jclass acl = env->GetObjectClass(nativeActivity);
  // Get the classloader
  jmethodID getClassLoader = env->GetMethodID(acl, "getClassLoader", "()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;");
  jobject cls = env->CallObjectMethod(nativeActivity, getClassLoader);
  jclass classLoader = env->FindClass("java/lang/ClassLoader");
  // find the loadclass function
  jmethodID findClass = env->GetMethodID(classLoader, "loadClass", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;");
  // Run the loadClass function for the flurry agent
  jstring strClassName = env->NewStringUTF("com/flurry/android/FlurryAgent");
  const char *path = env->GetStringUTFChars(strClassName, 0);
  // The following line will crash the app because it can't find the class files
  jclass flurry_agent_class = (jclass)(env->CallObjectMethod(cls, findClass, strClassName));
  env->DeleteLocalRef(strClassName);
  if (env->ExceptionCheck() || flurry_agent_class == 0) {
    Log("Failed to load flurry class!");
    env->ExceptionDescribe();
    env->ExceptionClear();
    return 0;
  }
  return flurry_agent_class;
}

void Flurry::SetStateAndStartSession(android_app *state) {
  state_ = state;
  JNIEnv *env = GetEnv(state->activity->vm);
  jclass flurry_agent_class = GetFlurryAgentClass(env);
  if (flurry_agent_class == 0) {
    return;
  }
  // Start session
  jmethodID onStartSession_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(flurry_agent_class, "onStartSession", "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
  if (onStartSession_method) {
    jstring api_key_string = env->NewStringUTF("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    Log("Starting native flurry");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(flurry_agent_class, onStartSession_method, state->activity->clazz, api_key_string);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(api_key_string);
  }
  // Set logging
  jmethodID setLogEnabled_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(flurry_agent_class, "setLogEnabled", "(Z)V");
  if (setLogEnabled_method) {
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(flurry_agent_class, setLogEnabled_method, JNI_TRUE);
  }
  // Set logging
  jmethodID setLogLevel_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(flurry_agent_class, "setLogLevel", "(I)V");
  if (setLogLevel_method) {
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(flurry_agent_class, setLogLevel_method, 2);
  }
  // Set events logging 
  jmethodID setLogEvents_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(flurry_agent_class, "setLogEvents", "(Z)V");
  if (setLogEvents_method) {
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(flurry_agent_class, setLogEvents_method, JNI_TRUE);
  }
  // Set https 
  jmethodID setUseHttps_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(flurry_agent_class, "setUseHttps", "(Z)V");
  if (setUseHttps_method) {
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(flurry_agent_class, setUseHttps_method, JNI_TRUE);
  }
  // Send the event
  const char *eventname = "Native interface start";
  jmethodID logEvent_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(flurry_agent_class, "logEvent", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
  if (logEvent_method) {
    Log("Sending Flurry Event: %s", eventname);
    jstring event_name = env->NewStringUTF(eventname);
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(flurry_agent_class, logEvent_method, state_->activity->clazz, event_name);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(event_name);
  }
  //LogEvent("Starting up native interface");
}

void Flurry::EndSession() {
  // End session
  JNIEnv *env = GetEnv(state_->activity->vm);
  jclass flurry_agent_class = GetFlurryAgentClass(env);
  if (flurry_agent_class == 0) {
    return;
  }
  jmethodID onEndSession_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(flurry_agent_class, "onEndSession", "(Landroid/content/Context;)V");
  if (onEndSession_method) {
    Log("Ending flurry");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(flurry_agent_class, onEndSession_method, state_->activity->clazz);
  }
}
```

The output log for the flurry calls seems consistent with the java based calls:

Sample Log output:

```
I/FlurryAgent(25878): Agent cache file doesn't exist.
I/MyApp(25878): Starting native flurry
I/MyApp(25878): Sending Flurry Event: Native interface start
D/FlurryAgent(25878): generating report
D/FlurryAgent(25878): Sending report to: https://data.flurry.com/aap.do
D/FlurryAgent(25878): Report successful
D/FlurryAgent(25878): Done sending initial agent report
D/FlurryAgent(25878): Ending session
```

I am at a complete loss why the events from Java are showing up while the Native calls and events are not. Please help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are calling the logEvent method with the wrong parameters:

```
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(flurry_agent_class, logEvent_method, state_->activity->clazz, event_name);
```

should be

```
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(flurry_agent_class, logEvent_method, event_name);
```

because the FlurryAgent.logEvent method only takes in a string, not a context.